# Can't get python class initialized correctly

Tags: python, class

I'm not sure why this isn't working. The error says my Artist object has no attribute called name. This doesn't make sense to me because I'm looking right at the attribute called name....

> Define the Artist class with a constructor to initialize an artist's
> information and a print_info() method. The constructor should by
> default initialize the artist's name to "None" and the years of birth
> and death to 0. print_info() should display Artist Name, born XXXX if
> the year of death is -1 or Artist Name (XXXX-YYYY) otherwise.
>
> Define the Artwork class with a constructor to initialize an artwork's
> information and a print_info() method. The constructor should by
> default initialize the title to "None", the year created to 0, and the
> artist to use the Artist default constructor parameter values.

Ex: If the input is:

```
Pablo Picasso
1881
1973
Three Musicians
1921
```

the output is:

```
Artist: Pablo Picasso (1881-1973)
Title: Three Musicians, 1921
```

If the input is:

```
Brice Marden
1938
-1
Distant Muses 
2000
```

the output is:

```
Artist: Brice Marden, born 1938
Title: Distant Muses, 2000
```

My code:

```
class Artist:
    def __init__(self, name= "None", birth_year = 0, death_year = 0):
        name = self.name
        birth_year = self.birth_year
        death_year = self.death_year
    # TODO: Define constructor with parameters to initialize instance attributes
    #       (name, birth_year, death_year)
    def print_info(self):
        if self.death_year == -1:
            print("{}, born {}".format(self.name,self.birth_year))
        else:
            print("{} ({}-{})".format(self.name,self,birth_year,self.death_year))
    # TODO: Define print_info() method. If death_year is -1, only print birth_year

      
class Artwork:
    def __init__(self,title ="None",year_created = 0, artist=Artist().name):
        title = self.title
        year_created = self.year_created
        artist = self.artist
    
    # TODO: Define constructor with parameters to initialize instance attributes
    #       (title, year_created, artist)
    def print_info(self):
        print("Artist: {}, born {}".format(self.artist,Artist().birth_year))
        print("Title: {}, {}".format(self.title,self.year_created))
        
    # TODO: Define print_info() method


if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_artist_name = input()
    user_birth_year = int(input())
    user_death_year = int(input())
    user_title = input()
    user_year_created = int(input())

    user_artist = Artist(user_artist_name, user_birth_year, user_death_year)

    new_artwork = Artwork(user_title, user_year_created, user_artist)
  
    new_artwork.print_info()
```

Enter program input (optional)

```
Pablo Picasso
1881
1973
Three Musicians
1921
```

Program errors displayed here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    class Artwork:
  File "main.py", line 17, in Artwork
    def __init__(self,title ="None",year_created = 0, artist=Artist().name):
  File "main.py", line 3, in __init__
    name = self.name
AttributeError: 'Artist' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: You need to assign to `self.name` not `name` in `Artist.__init__()` (and others). This is backwards: `name = self.name`. it should be `self.name = name`

Answer (score 1):

You have the class rules backwords in Artist.**init**()
Classes work so that:

```
Class MyClass:
   def __init__(name,date):
      self.name = name
      self.date = date
```

self.name is the class name that gets assigned the name when initialized so doing the opposite should return None or nothing if I'm correct. Just switch those 2 and then doing:

```
newClass = MyClass("Pablo","2019")
print(MyClass.name)
print(MyClass.date)
```

returns:

```
Pablo

2019
```

If date is date:str on the **init**() function then str() the date first.